# Apache RewriteCond with nordic/special characters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I got two domains that both point to the same server. One has only the default ascii characters, and one contains a nordic character. The one with the ascii characters are only supposted to be used for email, and the domain is simply redirected to the one with the special character. This works as intended.

Now, in my `.htaccess` file, I want to check if the domain (with the special character) is lacking `www`. If it does, I want to 301 redirect to the same domain with the `www` prefixed. This is the code I am currently using. It is more or less boilerplate that I have used many times before, and should be working:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.dømain\.no [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.dømain.no/$1[R=301,L]
```

Now, the problem is that this redirect is ALWAYS fired, even when the domain has the `www` prefix. I tried swapping the domain with the domain without the special character, and it worked as it should.

I have no idea why Apache does not play nicely with the special character in my domain. My theory is that `%{HTTP_HOST}` contains some sort of malformed content due to the letter ø, which leads to the condition always being true. Beyond that I can not see how I should express my condition otherwise to avoid this.

Is there any way of telling Apache to handle the character differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [IDN Conversion Tool](http://mct.verisign-grs.com/convertServlet?input=www.d%C3%B8main.no):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.xn--dmain-vua\.no [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.xn--dmain-vua.no/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked as a charm. I inspected the http request, and saw the actual domain in the inspector. Kind of gave it away.